# Hexo does not return post.categories or post.tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

So I'am using static site generator hexo.io and i ran into a problem

In index page I want to display only posts whose category is 'show'.
I assigned category in .md file as show in official docs.

```
---
layout: post
title: "doors"
categories:
- show
date: 2016-10-02 17:54:22
header-img: "1.jpg"
author: "default"
---
```

But it seems that category doesn't get assigned because when try to display it like this

```
<% site.posts.each(function(post){ %>
  <div class="post-preview col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="post-title">
              <%- post.categories || "Untitled" %>
                <% console.log(post.categories)%>
          </h2>
<% }); %>
```

In `<h2>` I get `[object Object]` instead of text `show`.
When I try to console `post.categories` I get following output in console

```
Query { data: [], length: 0 }
Query { data: [], length: 0 }
Query { data: [], length: 0 }
Query { data: [], length: 0 }
Query { data: [], length: 0 }
Query {
  data: 
   [ Document {
       name: 'show',
       _id: 'citstcz9q000f8zi5oij9o5dg',
       slug: [Getter],
       path: [Getter],
       permalink: [Getter],
       posts: [Getter],
       length: [Getter] } ],
  length: 1 }
Query { data: [], length: 0 }
```

Can someone tell what iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hexo is neat and I'm keen on making it work for me. The documentation doesn't care about Handlebars (which is what I prefer), so I had to do some wrangling. Came here to see if there was a fix and I figured it out on my own. Here you go!

```
{{#each site.posts.data}}
<section class="post-block inner-wrap">
  <h2 class="post-block__title"><a href="/thoughts/{{this.slug}}">{{this.title}}</a></h2>
  <h5 class="post-block__meta">
    posted in

    {{#each this.categories.data}}
      <a href="{{this.permalink}}" class="post-block__category">{{this.name}}</a>
    {{/each}}

    on <span class="post-block__date">{{this.date._d}}</span>
  </h5>

  <span class="post-block__content">{{{this.content}}}</span>
</section>
{{/each}}
```

Looks like you're using `ejs`, but I hope my code helps you find a solution!